# Restarting a countdown based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with a variable called 'Countdown' that counts down the days in my data frame even though some days have multiple entries (rows).

```
       full dates  Countdown  
0      2008-01-01       3652  
1      2008-01-02       3651  
2      2008-01-03       3650  
3      2008-01-04       3649  
4      2008-01-05       3648  
5      2008-01-06       3647
```

I would like the countdown variable to 'restart' after certain days. So I would like one countdown from 2008-01-01 to 2008-01-03 then 2008-01-03 to 2008-01-06, etc.

Desired output:

```
       full dates  Countdown  
0      2008-01-01       2
1      2008-01-02       1 
2      2008-01-03       0  
3      2008-01-04       2  
4      2008-01-05       1  
5      2008-01-06       0
```

My dataframe is much larger but the idea is the same: between two given days I would like to start a countdown and then 'restart' it at another day (in the example it 'restarted' on 2008-01-03 and 2008-01-06.

Comment: What is your expected out

Comment: I edited the question, thanks

Comment: For the days that have multiple entries, should the counter increment or stay the same? Basically, is the counter actually based on the number of days apart, or simply the number of rows?

Comment: It's based on the number of days apartment, not rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `pd.merge_asof`. Create a `DataFrame` of your right bin edges, then merge the closest edge and calculate the number of days until.

```
import pandas as pd

# Right bin edges for your countdowns. 
dates = ['2008-01-03', '2008-01-06']
df_dates = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.to_datetime(dates)})

# Convert original DataFrame to datetime
df['full dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['full dates'])

# Merge and calculate the Countdown value
df = pd.merge_asof(df, df_dates, left_on ='full dates', right_on ='date', direction='forward') 

df['Countdown'] = (df['date']-df['full dates']).dt.days
df = df.drop(columns='date')  # No longer needed
```

## Output: `df`

```
  full dates  Countdown
0 2008-01-01          2
1 2008-01-02          1
2 2008-01-03          0
3 2008-01-04          2
4 2008-01-05          1
5 2008-01-06          0
```

Comment: Thanks! But I am getting an error with this line 'df = pd.merge_asof(df, df_dates, left_on ='full dates', right_on ='date', direction='forward') '

Comment: TypeError: merge_asof() got an unexpected keyword argument 'direction'

Comment: @GrahamStreich what version of pandas? Because `The default is “backward” and is compatible in versions below 0.20.0. The direction parameter was added in version 0.20.0 and introduces “forward” and “nearest”.`

Comment: ahh, I'm in python 3

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html

Comment: I'm not sure what the 3.0 fix is

Comment: I just took out the parameter given it's the default. I am now getting an error with this line

Comment: df['Countdown'] = (df['date']-df['full dates']).dt.days

Comment: TypeError: data type "datetime" not understood

Comment: Not sure about the `datetime`. However, the direction is important for this to work.

Comment: I figured out the datetime issue. I can't figure out how to add the forward parameter....

Comment: this is what worked 'reload['date'].subtract(reload['full dates'])' to get around '(df['date']-df['full dates']).dt.days'

Comment: Probably to upgrade pandas.